# Problem with pointer on ARM Cortex M4

Tags: stm32

I am working on a STM32f4 board and I have a problem with passing pointer as input in a function.
I have my main :

```
    float32_t var;
    function(&var);
```

And my function :

```
    void function(float32_t* x){
        *x = 1.;
    }
```

But, oddly, when I debug this code, the x address doesn't fit the var address (x address is 0x00000000 pointer in function) and the value of var is not 1 after function calling.
Why do I have this problem ? Moreover, this kind of function worked efficiently...

In fact, I found a new bug, once I launched the debugger a error occurs

> No source available for ""

I never had this message...

I use the GCC GNU ARM compiler with these options :

```
     -mcpu=cortex-m4; -mthumb; -Wall; -ffunction-sections; -g; -O0; -fno-builtin; -DSTM32F407VG; -DSTM32F4XX; -I.;
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what the C standards say about `1.` I've always used `1.0` which might be worth a try. It might also be worth adding complete compilable code along with details on the compiler you're using.

Comment: I use the library given by ST and the core-m4 driver. The compiler is GNU GCC ARM with theses options : _-mcpu=cortex-m4; -mthumb; -Wall; -ffunction-sections; -g; -O0; -fno-builtin;; -DSTM32F407VG; -DSTM32F4XX; -I.;_

Comment: `= 1.` Looks odd to me too..

Comment: For the 1., I already tested the two ways to write it (1. and 1.0) and both work.

Comment: You can edit that extra info into the question to make it cleaer, sometimes comments get hidden as more are posted. Do you have a way to test the code works (maybe send to a serial port / LCD etc)? That would help isolate if it's a code generation problem or just a debugger problem.

Comment: This can simply be a debugger bug. Can you use any other ways to check that the pointer is null? Like for example compare it to null inside the function and do something if it's null?

Comment: Its a debugger problem because I started a new projet with the same code and it worked. But I launched again a new debugging session and error came again : _No source available for ""_

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a simple case of bad linking, because some of your object files aren't up to date, while the prototype of the function has changed.

Try clean away all your .o-files, and rebuild your source.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can explain why the Debugger launches this error at the start :

`No source available for ""`

Thks.

Comment: It's a little tough since you haven't told us what debugger you are using. However, I have seen this when using gdb in Eclipse, and as soon as I start running the code it finds the source files and displays them properly.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the compiler optimized away your instructions (although you specified -O0 which should disable optimizations).

Can you try to define your variable as

volatile float32_t var;

And then try again?